Perturbation of zeros of functions in the Cartwright class
An entire function $F$ of exponential type belongs to the Cartwright class, if
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{\max \{ \log |F(x)|,0 \}}{1+x^2} \, dx < \infty.
$$
Suppose that $F$ belongs to the Cartwright class and has zero set $Z = (z_n)_n \subseteq \mathbb C$. Further let $(p_n)_n$ be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb C$. Is it true that $(z_n+p_n)_n$ is the zero set of a function belonging to the Cartwright class?

Theorem 1 here should clarify this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701808.pdf
